# How to fetch the google calendar event in custom application

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, google-calendar-api

I know that this question is duplication of the many question. but i need help for get calendar event from google calendar. I follow the instruction of this guide line.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios

after download the file from git.

I follow the step in tutorial but stuck at below step, this is in step b. first step

> google-api-objectivec-client/Source/GTL.xcodeproj

I am not able to find the any project like "GTL", there is one project called "GTLCore".

So is there any demo which have done this thing. Any help would be appreciable.

**Update:**
After add GTLCore i move ahead but in step D. , Step E. and Step F. was not able to perform because no such file or framework exist.

> **Step D.** Select the "GTL" project's "GTLTouchStaticLib" target and make the following changes:
>
> > Add the library GTMSessionFetcher/libGTMSessionFetcherLib.a to Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries.
> >
> > Add the absolute path to gtm-session-fetcher/Source/ to Build Settings > User Header Search Paths.
> >
> > Add the flag GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER=1 to Build Settings > Preprocessor Macros.
>
> **Step E.** Delete the "GTL" project's "GTLFramework" target.
>
> **Step F.** In the Project navigator, delete GTL project's GTL Source > Common > HTTPFetcher group.

Comment: Can you provide the full error message from your XCode log window? Or can you upload your project to GitHub, so other people can reproduce the issue?

Comment: But how i make the project if i cannot follow the step.@ztan